# How to mount an NTFS filesystem, allowing all users full access?

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems, mount, ntfs

How could I mount an NTFS filesystem in a way that would allow all users full access to it? If I use `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /media/drive`, then only the root user can use it. It won't let me change the permissions/ownership on files after it's mounted (although folders are ok), which is really annoying.

Comment: tried `ntfs-3g` ? assuming you have the package with the same name?

Comment: @D0rf i think that the `ntfs` option for mount uses ntfs-3g, it has dones so for a while now.

Comment: @terdon thank you for the comment, it indeed seems to happen that way.

Comment: Just to note that I solved a similar problem by installing the `ntfs-3g` package which I was missing. Maybe could be useful to someone.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [man mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount):

> ### Mount options for ntfs
>
> ︙
>   **uid**=*value*, **gid**=*value* and **umask**=*value*
>
>   Set the file permission on the filesystem. The umask value is given in octal.
>     By default, the files are owned by root and not readable by somebody else.

So you should be able to do what you're after with something like

```
mount -t ntfs -o umask=000 /dev/sda1 /media/drive
```

which should give everyone read and write permissions on the volume.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Is there a way to add this to /etc/fstab, so that it may mount automatically with all permissions?

Comment: Sure! You can use the same arguments in fstab as in the `mount` command; see `man 5 fstab` or the web equivalent for details on the format, or the leading comments which may be included in `/etc/fstab` on the system where you're looking to make the change.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, perhaps you need the allow_other option?

```
mount -t ntfs -o umask=000,allow_other /dev/sda1 /media/drive
```