# Everyone has read/write/execute permission, but no one can create files

Tags: permissions, mount, ntfs, raspberry-pi

I mounted my USB hard drive using the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/589763/how-to-mount-an-ntfs-filesystem-allowing-all-users-full-access) and, well:

```
$ sudo mount -t ntfs -o umask=000 -rw /dev/sda1 "/media/MyBook/"
$ ls -l /media
total 12
(a couple irrelevent directories here)
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Apr 28 11:11 MyBook
$ touch /media/MyBook/test
touch: cannot touch `/media/MyBook/test': Permission denied
$ sudo touch /media/MyBook/test
touch: cannot touch `/media/MyBook/test': Permission denied
```

So despite `rwx` permissions for everyone, no one, not even root, can create files on the drive. The permissions are the same on the `/media` folder & all of `/media/MyBook`'s subfolders. I've `chkdsk /F`'d the drive in Windows; it works fine on there and on Ubuntu. I've also tried `chmod 777`ing and `chown`ing the folders I need to write to; nothing works. What's going on?

Output of `mount` (no arguments):

```
/dev/root on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=216132k,nr_inodes=54033,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=44880k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=89740k)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda1 on /media/MyBook type ntfs (rw,relatime,uid=0,gid=0,umask=00,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1)
```

Update: The Pi's primary filesystem is an SD card, and I just noticed the card's switch is in the 'lock' position. <strike>I can't confirm that was the cause until I finish `chkdsk`ing the drive (AGAIN) but it sounds likely...I guess?</strike> Finally took care of that...it wasn't the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: did you check the logs to check if the mount is effectively rw, and not ro?

Comment: @stijn I checked `/var/log/syslog` but all i saw was this (with a timestamp): `raspberrypi kernel: [256240.537351] NTFS volume version 3.1.`

Comment: can you post the output of `mount` then? Invoked witout arguments it just displays what's mounted and how..

Comment: @stijn I added it.

Comment: seems fine - but I just noticed that umask.. I cannot test this atm, but I'm pretty sure you need to add somthing like uid=pi,gid=pi,umask=0222 to the mount line

Comment: @stijn That set the owner and group correctly (when I put my username in the `uid` option instead of `pi`), but now the permissions show it's read-only: `dr-xr-xr-x 1 adam pi   4096 May 21 08:58 MyBook`

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you make any modifications to the disk?  Create files in other directories, append to existing files, or delete existing files?

Comment: Maybe related (yes, I know it’s for Vista, not *nix): [How to recover write privileges for USB devices?](http://superuser.com/questions/597799/how-to-recover-...)

Comment: @Scott Trying to create a folder gives "Operation not permitted".

Answer (score 1):

use

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o umask=0022,uid=adam,gid=pi,rw /dev/sda1 /media/MyBook
```

(note the umask!)

or better, since you'r using an rpi which has the `udisks` command just use that so you do not have to manually run the mount command:

```
udisks --mount /dev/sda1
```

this normally picks the correct options automatically

Comment: Still getting 'permission denied'...Also, I really need it mounted so ANYONE can write to it; I'm (trying) to use it with Apache and the Transmission daemon.

Comment: and the same command with umask=0000?

Comment: It shows `rwx` permission for everyone, which is what I want, but it still says "permission denied" when I try to create a file.